# How do I specify a custom exception message from my ability.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cancan, cancancan

In my `ability.rb`, I have the following rule:

```
elsif user.has_role? :demo
  can :read, Profile, demo_featured: true, demo_linked: true, message: "To access this profile, please subscribe here."
```

But that doesn't produce the message I want.

How do I get this specific rule to produce the message I want?

**Edit 1**

Here is the full `ability.rb` `if` condition:

```
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    alias_action :create, :show, :new, :destroy, to: :csnd

    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.has_role? :coach
      # do some stuff
    elsif user.has_role? :demo
      can :read, Profile, demo_featured: true, demo_linked: true
    elsif user.has_role? :player
      # can do some stuff
    else
      can :read, Profile
    end    
  end
```

These are some bits from my `ProfilesController`:

```
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :invite_user, :profiles]

    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.published.includes(:grades, :positions, :achievements, :videos, :transcripts).friendly.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Comment: What is with the ELSIF condition. Is the IF condition existing somewhere before the ELSIF condition? I a m thinking that's the problem.

Comment: Post your controller code. You have to catch the exception in your controller and use its message in the flash or alert part of the response, as stated here: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Exception-Handling. Having ability.rb produce the right exception is only half the job.

Comment: @mlabarca What specifically within my controller are you looking for? My controller is beastly, so just trying to narrow it down for you.

Comment: @mlabarca Actually, there is nothing specific about this logic in my `ProfilesController#Show`. What should I put there? The issue is that the logic works, I just want the message customized. I also updated the question with more code.

Comment: @marcamillion so it sounds like you're wanting to specify custom messages for a flash alert from a model – is that correct?

Comment: @marcamillion any luck with any of the answers below? if so, mark the accepted answer or post what you did that finally solved it.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for:

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Exception-Handling

Comment: Thats what led me to try the above. But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

The [cancan docs](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Exception-Handling) give examples of customizing the message when you `authorize!` in the controller, and when you manually raise an error, but there doesn't seem to be any mechanism for specifying messages in `ability.rb`.

Instead, you could catch and modify it in your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    if current_user.has_role? :demo
      redirect_to :back, :alert => "To access this profile, please subscribe here."
    end
    # render 403, etc.
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied` in your main application controller or in your specific controller. It should do something like redirecting to a login page. In my case it's something like this:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do ||
  redirect_to new_user_session_path
end
```

Since you're producing a different exception message and then displaying it it'd probably be like this, using the flash:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  flash[:notice] = exception.message
  redirect_to new_user_session_path
end
```

Your own logic may vary depending on how you want to handle when the user doesn't have access. It's possible you may even have it setup in a per-controller basis, but this should be the gist of it.